# Want to add onclick attr but not trigger click

Tags: jquery, onclick, click, jquery-events

I want to add an onclick attribute to an input that is coming from some JSON.  The JSON is being processed by datatables, but I feel like my lack of understanding is related to jQuery and not the datatables.

The input, in its unaltered form from the JSON is:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="unique-string-submit_payment" id="id_unique-string-submit_payment" />
```

I would like the input to get altered to:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="unique-string-submit_payment" id="id_unique-string-submit_payment" onclick="performFunction('some info')" />
```

If I change the backend code to include the onclick, it works perfectly.  However if I try to alter the input via jQuery, the function is 'clicked' as the page is loaded.  Here are a couple things I've tried:

```
$('#data-display tbody tr td input').on('click', performFunction('some info'));
$('#data-display tbody tr td input').attr('onclick', performFunction('some info'));
$('#data-display tbody tr td input').each(function(){
    $(this).attr('onclick', performFunction('some info'));
});
```

What am I missing here?  Isn't on supposed to setup the click waiting for the trigger, not trigger it?  Is adding an attr of onclick actually a way of triggering an event?

I can modify the backend, so its not essential that I resolve this, but I know I am missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple!

```
$('#data-display tbody tr td input').on('click', performFunction('some info'));
$('#data-display tbody tr td input').attr('onclick', performFunction('some info'));
```

on and attr are waiting for function reference, but, doing that, you are calling performFunction right now.

If you want to solve your problem, replace your code with this one:

```
$('#data-display tbody tr td input').on('click', function() { performFunction('some info') });
$('#data-display tbody tr td input').attr('onclick', function() { performFunction('some info') });
```

Comment: Thank you, i think i have this basic error in jquery frequently.  Perhaps it will stick now :)